# Need to implement ETL logic of generating sequence number through Pig Script

Tags: apache-pig, etl

I have a current ETL Logic which I have to implement in pig.
ETL Logic is creating a unique sequence number for the column if incoming value is null or blank.

Need to do this through pig.

Comment: So what is stopping you?

Answer (score 0):

you can generate sequence number using RANK but in your condition it is little bit different you are checking if that value is either '0' or 'null' then only you are assigning sequence number..

My point of view you should use UDF for this..

```
package pig.test;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

public class SequenceNumber extends EvalFunc<Integer> {
    static int cnt = 0;
    public Integer exec(Tuple v) throws IOException{
        int a = (Integer)v.get(0);

        if(a == 0) {
            cnt++ ;
            return new Integer(cnt);
        }
        else
            return new Integer(a);
    }

}
```

In pig:

```
--Replace all null with 0 

Step-1 A1 = foreach A generate *, (id is null ? 0 : id) as sq;
Step-2 T1 = foreach A1 generate sq,<your_fields>,<your_fields>; 
Step-3 Result = foreach T1 generate sqno(*),<your_fields>,<your_fields>;
```

Hope this will help!!